# Remove comma from a list

Tags: formatting

I have this type of thing again and again in a long list: 
 Row[{"F", ",", "G"}] and  Row[{"B[Flat]", ",", "A"}] etc.
 I want these automatically replaced by "F","G" and "B[Flat]","A"
etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{Row[{"F", ",", "G"}], Row[{"B[Flat]", ",", "A"}]} /. Row[x_] :> Select[x, # != "," &]
(* {{"F", "G"}, {"B[Flat]", "A"}} *)
```

Comment: Works, thanks a lot.

Comment: @QuasarSupernova You are welcome. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

```
Row[DeleteCases[First[Row[{"F", ",", "G"}]], ","]]
```

Comment: This gives FG. I want F,G